# Creating File in Map funcion with Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop

I followed the guide

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

for settings two slaves with file conf/master = "master" and conf/slaves = "slave_uno slave_due".

Now, i will try to create file on the FS on the SO in function map with my hadoop application but this file is created only one slave.

As I create them in both slaves? As should I configure hadoop?

thank's all :)

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question.

Comment: Do you mean to create a file in HDFS in your map method, and at the moment, the file is only appearing on the local filesystem of the node that ran the map task?

Comment: Hi, thanks fro reply. I want to create a File (java.io) on local FileSystem (no filesystem HDFS) for each map fase on each slaves.